# Magento 2.4: Change price filter text and range programmatically

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation, filter

I want to change the price filter text and range on the layered navigation from:
[image]

To:

Something like this:

Under  $30.00

$30.00 - $60.00

$60.00 - $90.00

$90.00 - $120.00

$120.00 and Above

How can it be done programmatically?